Choosing trace width and spacing
What is the standard for choosing trace width and spacing? I keep finding various and different answers. My goal is to go as small as possible for my board.
Everything is low current; nothing should be over 65mA.
I am working with various power rails 24V and below that. 12V, 10V, 5V, 3.3V, 1.2V, -3.3V, -2V.
Thank you!

Conductor spacing as a function of voltage and device type is given in the IPC-2221 standard. The Saturn PCB design toolkit has a calculator for the spacing:

Conductor widths are also listed in the IPC-2221 standard, but have been superseded by IPC-2152. The Saturn PCB design toolkit also has a calculator for this:


Also consider the minimum width/spacing your PCB fab can make. Smaller width/spacing might limit you to thinner copper, a potential issue if you need more than 2oz copper. It might also make the board cost more.
